# TypeError: Cannot read property 'NormalModule' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

I am working on a big project and I cannot run it anymore because of this error:

When I run **npm run serve**

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'NormalModule' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'NormalModule' of undefined
    at VueLoaderPlugin.apply (/Users/<user>/muso-ninjas/node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/pluginWebpack5.js:44:47)
    at webpack (/Users/<user>/muso-ninjas/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:51:13)
    at serve (/Users/<user>/muso-ninjas/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/serve.js:163:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Please help me because I am stuck and I would like to go with my project.

Comment: Check https://forum.vuejs.org/t/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-normalmodule/123631

Comment: Make sure the used versions of 'sass' and 'sass-loader' are compatible as well. For me that was the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this first:

1. In your project root, run `npm install`. Maybe someone else on your project has changed/added a dependency, and pulling from your git repo got you the code that relies on this, but won't get you the dependency itself.

If that doesn't fix your issue, try this:

1. Remove the `node_modules` folder in your project root.
2. Update your Node.js version to the latest 16.x version.
   2.1 Verify the update has worked by issuing `node -v` in the terminal.
3. Update your `npm`: Run `npm i -g npm` in the terminal.
   3.1 Very the update has worked by issuing `npm -v` in the terminal.
4. Run `npm install` in your project's root folder.

If this doesn't fix your issue, you need to find help from someone else on your team.

Comment: when I run "npm i -g npm", I get an error saying i can't ise "g" flag, instead I should use "--location=global" instead to install it globally. So I ran "npm i --location=global npm", but I get error: 

code EBADENGINE
engine Unsupported engine
engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.1.0
notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.1.0
notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.11.0","node":"v16.15.0"}

Comment: @AliGuliyev Maybe you don't have admin rights on your machine?

Comment: @conexo, what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in link from the first comment, I deleted node_modules, replaced the node-sass in package.json with "sass": "^1.26.5" and ran **npm install** but it didn't work.

Then I repeated the steps and removed package-lock.json as well.

This helped and the app was served properly

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use yarn to install the dependencies, and it worked like magic. I was amazed. Here are the steps:

First, download and install yarn

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Then, use this command to install the dependencies

```
yarn install
```

After that, you can run it with npm or yarn.

```
npm run serve
```

And that's it! Do try it.

Answer (score -1):

npm install webpack@4.39.3 --save

Answer (score -1):

1 yarn remove webpack
2 yarn add webpack.
// the problem is the webpack version, so by installing the last version everything works as before.